# return a string containing billion characters

Tags: string, c#-4.0

Hi i have a function that takes an integer number n and returns a string that contains the numbers from 1 to n separated by ','. Now this number integer n could be any number as large as 1 billion. What could be the best solution for this. And how do i manage the memory related issues like if the RAM is just 2 Gb so what would happen if i return this big string in C#. The function signature is:

```
string convtostr (int n)
{}
```

so the input for e.g. could be n = 5, then output would be a string like this
    "1,2,3,4,5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method footprint must exactly match that which you show, then it cannot be done. Because you cannot inherit `String` and make a new better type that will work for >2GB

If your assumption about the maximum input value of `n` is incorrect then you can provide a working solution to match the footprint. Such as if the max value of `n` was `10000` or something very small.

However I think the `IEnumerable<char>` approach as suggested by @MikeSamuel is the only answer that would present a working solution that returns close to the stated requirements.

As you have tagged this `c# 4.0` Most likely they were looking for a solution that used `yield` syntax such as:

```
static IEnumerable convtostr(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        yield return string.Format("{0}, ", i.ToString());
    yield return n.ToString();
}
```

you can then explain that you use it like the following

```
int input = 1000000000; // 1 billion.

foreach (var value in convtostr(input))
{
    Console.Write(value );
}
```

And that is likely what they were wanting you to answer with. As this will work with very little active RAM by not actually storing the whole final string in memory.

Edit: another answer similar to that suggested by @suddnely_me is to pass in an action for each number instead, such as:

```
static void convtostr(int n, Action<int> action)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        action(i);
}
```

This is then called using:

```
int input = 1000000000; // 1 billion.
convtostr(input, n =>
    {
        if (n < input) { Console.Write("{0}, ", n); }
        else { Console.Write(n); }
    });
```

Which will actually perform almost the same as using the `yield` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create such a large string in .NET. 2GB is the maximum size of an object, regardless of how much memory you have.

Instead of returning a string, you could provide an object which allows you to iterate over the characters in the result but only calculates them on demand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this was asked to me in an interview question . Anyways even if i return an object, the result to be iterated would still be very large. So is there any to get around or is it just not possible.

Comment: @Naphstor: Get around what?  If you want to iterate over it then it's going to take a long time however you do it. If you don't need to iterate over it, then obviously the lazy approach will be very fast because it won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best solution for you is not to use this string at all :) You may wrap this string in a class, containing only the number n:

```
class LargeStringWithNumbers
{
  int upper_bound;
  public void Print()
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < upper_bound; j++ )
    {
      System.Console.Write("{0};", j);
    }
    System.Console.Write("\n");
  }
}
```

It will behave exactly like if you contained the string all the time, except you don't.

Comment: Hmmmm. What I mean, is that I see no purpose to **return** such a string, since the string is only a representation of some object. In the very basic application - this object is just an int. If you need to perform some operations of this object, you can enhance its implementation. For example, with lower bound j, such as print of the object will look like j,...,i etc.

Comment: By the way, I see your comment about the interview, so I guess my answer would the the 'correct' (hmmmm...) one.

Comment: thats right but it was specifically asked in an interview. and they wanted to check about the memory model or something in C#.

Comment: If you combine Mark's answer with mine, you get it right :) The answer is "It's impossible due to <Mark's answer>, but it's also not needed since <my answer>".

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the design limit:

n = 1 billion:

when n is one billion, then the commas "," alone eat your available space since char === 2 bytes; so that 2 bytes * 1 billion = 2 GB - 2 bytes (you actually have 2 billion - 1 commas). Hence, from this basic observation the idea must be to compress the result to fit in 2GB. String is an object and the size is restricted to 2GB.

Therefore the question is how do you encode messages between objects? I.e one object will call the function with n and expects a message from the called object. Notice that you were not asked to print the result, but rather to return a string. If the function signature you present is actually what the interviewer wrote on the board (as opposed to it being your interpretation of the question) then the answer from suddnly_me won't do, otherwise it is your answer.

Assuming that the signature is what the interviewer wrote, so how do you send the compressed message between the two objects? As facetious as it may sound, I would return n as a string.

```
 string convtostr (int n)
 {
  return n+"";
 }
```

Then depending on what the returned value will be used for, I would write decoders/parsers to decode the message. For example, if the call needs to write the string to a file, then a writer method/function would convert the string back to an int and the iterate from 1 to n while writing to the file.

I have gone on long enough. You get the idea.

Comment: yes thanks i actually thought of doing the same. but i guess he wanted to hear something else. coz he kept on saying that your input is n = 1billion and so the output you return will be return "1,2,3,4,...,1Gb"; So i got confused.